# Where is the dump file of windows store app on windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I can't find any dump file in test or publish enviroment when my windows store app crashs, instead the app just automatica terminate.
How can I got dump file in test device or in dashboard, does something must done first?

Answer (score 2):

**`C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive`**

This location have the crash logs for apps. Please locate your apps folder and get the **`Report.wer`** file

Comment: Thx, I found the **report.wer** file.
But it seems windbg can't analyze wer file directly, do anyone how get **.dump** file from this **.wer** file?

Comment: I'm also not able to figure it out :( if you will get some solution do notify me.